# XCode won't compile with Kinvey : file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) i386 slice

Tags: xcode, kinvey

I am new to Xcode, New to Kinvey.. Fun start..

I followed Kinvey's installation guide for iOS and everything goes pretty well until I try to compile.The Presence of the Kinvey Framework in my project blocks it from compiling with the following error:

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) i386 slice: /Users/*path_to_my_project*/KinveyKit.framework/KinveyKit for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Looking around at other solutions, nothing seems to fit.. Note that the issue is on i386, not armv7s..

I tried on Xcode 4.6.1 and Xcode 4.6.3 with brand new projects with nothing in them..

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: There is a bug in KinveyKit 1.19.1. A fixed version is now available: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/downloads

Comment: This applies only to KinveyKit 1.19.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Kinvey, it was found that it was a Bug in the 1.19.1 SDK. It has been fixed in the 1.19.2. Kinvey has been pretty reactive on this.

This question can be closed now.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue awhile back in our project. I believe if you go into the build settings for your main app target and set the property ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH (Build Active Architecture Only) to NO, that should fix your issue.